# tk_choose.files with UNIX and R

Tags: r, file, unix

I am a bit new to R, but I think I have a fairly simple program, which works well except that it does not actually accept multiple files. If I try to manually type in two different files it claims neither exists. Here is the code:

```
library("lattice")
library("tcltk")

File.names<-(tk_choose.files(default="", caption="Choose your files", multi=TRUE, filters=NULL, index=1))
Num.Files<-NROW(File.names)

file<- read.table(File.names,header=TRUE)

colnames(file) <- c(1:18)

histoCol <- c(file$'14')

histogram(histoCol, col=1, xlim=range(c(histoCol)), main='Test',ylab='Percent',  xlab='Greater than 30x Coverage')
```

And the files that I am trying to enter all follow this methodology:

```
Targ  cov  av_cov  87A_cvg  87Ag  87Agr  87Agr  87A_gra  87A%_1   87A%_3   87A%_5   87A%_10  87A%_20                    
1:028 400  0.42    400     0.42    1       1       2       41.8    0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     
1:296 5599  39.99   5599    39.99   34      42      50      100.0   100.0   100.0   100.0   93.6 
1:453 334  0.63    334     0.63    1       2       2       62.1    0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0  
1:427 6932  49.51   6932    49.51   48      52      57      100.0   100.0   100.0   100.0   100.0
1:736 27562  124.15  27562   124.15  97      123     157     100.0   100.0   100.0   100.0   100.0
1:514 2340  16.71   2340    16.71   13      17      21      100.0   100.0   100.0   95.7    40.0 
1:296 8202  49.71   8202    49.71   23      43      80      100.0   100.0   100.0   100.0   81.2
1:534 3950  28.21   3950    28.21   22      33      36      100.0   100.0   100.0   100.0   76.4
```

I am running this from the commandline (UNIX) but so far everything I have read indicated that as long as I had the `multi=TRUE` line it should work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe `nrow` must be given in lowercase. Also, I believe it should read `histoCol <- file[,14]`. What do you want the program to do when the user selects multiple files?

Comment: @KarstenW. I would like it to produce multiple histograms. One for each file.

Comment: you have `File.names` as a character vector. Looping over each and creating the graphic you want is what is needed.

Comment: @jverzani What do you mean? Looping over each what? And if you mean each file then would it be better to use file.choose rather than choose.file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what jverzani was suggesting:

```
> for ( i in seq_along(File.names) ) { assign( paste0("fil_", i), 
                                          read.table(File.names[i] ) ) }
> ls(patt="fil_")
[1] "fil_1" "fil_2" "fil_3" "fil_4" "fil_5"
```

Comment: Can you explain this code?  How does it work with 
colnames(file) <- c(1:18)? If I try to implement this as is, it comes up with this error: Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = 1:18) : attempt to set colnames on object with less than two dimensions
Execution halted

Comment: I have no idea how to "explain how it works with colnames(file) <- c(1:18)". The example you used doesn't have 18 columns and the vector 1:18 would not be valid R column names for a dataframe anyway. What I offered did import 5 selected files from my filesystem using the tk interface for selection.

Comment: The example didn't have 18 columns because it would have looked a right mess if I had placed the entire file there as an example. If you were to change that to colnames(file) <- c(1:10) it would very well fit into the example. The purpose of that line is to change the column names so that they do not have the % in them, which is want to cause problems in R.

Comment: If you can neither explain how your code will help solve my problem nor any willingness to explain then I cannot select your answer. Thank you for your attempt, at any rate.

Comment: The column names would not have "%" in them anyway, since `check.names()` gets run on them as part of `read.table()` so the invalid characters got pulled out or replaced with 'dots'. If you replace the resulting colnames with versions that are invalid because they start with numbers then you are taking a big step backwards. I cannot explain how my code "will help solve your problem" because your problem statement remains unclear.

Comment: Ah, I see. My problem was originally that I could not select more than one file. Your code did allow me to select more than one but it resulted in the error I reported in the first comment because I did not fully understand your code or your intention. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: You are also going to need a looping construct to work through the dataframes one by one and not overwrite the results.